# iOS sockets: communication with Maya

Tags: ios, sockets, maya

Using this very helpful [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server), I've been able to put together a test ([video](https://vimeo.com/60357554)) of socket communication between the iOS Simulator and Maya. This is working very well with the simulator and localhost. However, when I test it on my device over the same wireless network, the iOS application just hangs with no connection with Maya (upon connection, there's a little "heads-up" message that displays).

I'm new to iOS programming and socket programming in particular, but I'm wondering if I'm missing anything. Here's the method I'm calling with the "connect" button press:

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {

    //assign text inputs to variables
    self.ipAddress = self.inputIPAddress.text;
    self.portNumber = [self.inputPortNumber.text intValue];

    //create streams and use variables to populate connection method
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;    
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)(self.ipAddress), self.portNumber, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    //send initial message to Maya
    NSString *initResponse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cmds.headsUpMessage('connected to iPhone')"];
    NSData *initData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[initResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[initData bytes] maxLength:[initData length]];

    //need some error checking or timeout mechanism
}
```

Like I said, works like a charm with localhost, but fails over the wireless network.

Comment: When you connect from localhost, you may be bypassing the software firewall (if present), but when connecting from another IP address, you are subjected to it.  Perhaps the firewall rules need to permit connections?  Alternatively: is the host process listening on a real network IP address, or only on the localhost loopback address?

Comment: Also, the comment at the bottom of your code regarding *"need some error checking or timeout mechanism"* .. this is a perfect opportunity to implement one, and see what kind of error comes back. You might also consider using asynchronous communications.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Chris. I determined it wasn't the firewall because I was able to run another app that connected with Maya. I think you were on to something with the localhost loopback issue, as my solution seems to indicate that I need to tell Maya to specify the ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found my own answer by digging through someone else's python script for creating a commandPort in Maya. It actually isn't due to the iOS code at all. It turns out that in Maya I need to create a commandPort using not only a port number but also the ip address. My mistake was that I assumed the commandPort knew the local ip address or didn't care. Apparently it cares.

Before (simplified code):

```
cmds.commandPort (n=':6328', stp='python')
```

After:

```
cmds.commandPort (n='192.168.2.7:6328', stp='python')
```